# SMTPSenderRefused error while sending emails from office365 with Django send_mail in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: django, office365, digital-ocean

I have one problem sending mails from office 365(Godaddy) with django send_mail in ubuntu 16.04 DigitalOcean.

### This is my actual configuration:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.office365.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "myuser"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

### Sending mail:

```
context = {}
subject = 'Verificación de registro con 1 clic'
txt_ = get_template("registration/emails/verify.txt").render(context)
from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
recipient_list = [somemail@somemail.com]
html_ = get_template("registration/emails/verify.html").render(context)
sent_mail = send_mail(
    subject,
    txt_,
    from_email,
    recipient_list,
    html_message=html_,
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

### This is the error raised:

```
raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM []', '=?utf-8?q?myuser?= <myemail@myemail.com>')
```

Answer (score -2):

That is because of several reasons. More common among them is if your **Allow Less secure apps** feature is turned off.

This https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255 might be very useful for you.

> **Google says**»
>
> If "Less secure app access" is turned off for your account, you can [turn it back on](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps). We recommend switching to [more secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255#more-secure-apps-how) instead.

It means, you just directly visit https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps and turn on.

You can also visit https://myaccount.google.com/security and Ctrl+F/Command+F » `Less secure app access` and under that you can see something like in the below attached image.

[image]

---

#### How I fixed this?

In my case I was getting below error while integrating **django-db-mailer**.

```sh
SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError z25sm26247003pfn.7 - gsmtp', 'rishikesh0011115067@gmail.com')
```

I fixed it by changing, EMAIL_USER -> EMAIL_HOST_USER settings variable.

Now, next error I got was exactly like your.

```sh
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials m123sm26024478pfb.133 - gsmtp')
```

I visited  https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps and found **Allow less secure apps** feature is turned off for my account. Just toggled the button's status and ran the code.

Finally succeeded. I hope, this might help you. You can also check if you're struggling https://devanswers.co/allow-less-secure-apps-access-gmail-account/. Already, it's too many days but still I preferred to answer by pointing you (Even though, you have already fixed it).

Comment: that's for gmail. My problem is with outlook specifically with office265 email.

Comment: This is for google. The question was specifically for office365